# My routes index.js file gives error (Module not found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The error says "Cannot find module './routes/index'" but clearly it is in that folder (even when static is set to that folder)

Here is the error:

```
root@ip*censored*:/home/ubuntu/*censored*# module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './routes/index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/*censored*/routes/index.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Here is what my directory looks like:

```
-bin
-forbiddenDirectory
-Node_modules
-public
-routes
-----index.js
-----users.js
-views
app.js
main.js
bundle.js
package.json
```

This is in my app.js:

```
var routes = require("./routes/index");
app.use('/', routes);
```

This is in my index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "http://news.google.com";
var ep = new aws.Endpoint('censored.us-west-1.censored.com');
var db = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({      // Dynamo database constructor
    "apiVersion": '2012-08-10',
    "region": 'us-west-1',
    "endpoint": ep,
    "accessKeyId": 'censored',
    "secretAccessKey": '+censored/censored'
});
var dateObj = new Date();
var dbTimeStamp = dateObj.toLocaleString();

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  next();
});


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

//module.exports = router;
module.exports = function(req,res,next) { res.render('index')}
```

So it is clearly in the routes folder but it doesn't read it for some reason. I tried everything... I tried changing ./routes/index to ./routes/index.js,  to ./routes/, then ./routes, then /routes, then tried routes/index/, then did ../routes/index same with .js afterwards. I give up and need your guys help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding file extension. So your code in app.js will be:

```
var routes = require("./routes/index.js"); 
app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: Just did that and still getting the "Cannot find module" error. 
var routes = require("./routes/index.js");

Comment: Did you try to remove dot from patch like ./routes... to /routes or in app.use add dot like app.use('/', routes) to app.use('./', routes) ?

Comment: Yeah I just tried all that and still getting the error. Lol this is frustrating

Comment: Hmm... The only thing I can advise is add full patch to routes file and if you are running app from terminal try adding sudo (on windows run cmd as admin) or if you are using any GUI app for building try to run this app as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

**you should use this code in index.js :**

```
exports.index=function(req,res,next){
  res.render('index');
}
```

**in your app.js :**

```
app.use('/', routes.index);
```

Comment: I did that and I still get the error. I put:

module.exports = router, function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('index'); 

in the end

Comment: put `module.exports = function(req,res,next) { res.render('index')}` can you log your routes type in app.js use `console.log(typeof routes)`

Comment: I put "console.log(typeof routes);" in app.js? I did that but its not even giving the result in the terminal because its still being overwritten by the "Cannot find module ./routes/index" error for some reason

Comment: So I found out the line that gives the error is "var routes = require("./routes/index");"

when I take it out with the uncoment //   the server runs without error (but it doesn't lead to index.js if so). But when I add it, it gives "Cannot find module ./routes/index" error

Comment: certainly its because your index.js module does not export any module and your path to index.js is correct can you show your updated index.js complete code?

Comment: I just uploaded the full index.js content

Comment: What do I define routes as? I'm using var routes = require('./routes/index'); 
 and its still giving error with your updated code. should I change it to something else?

Comment: Oh I think I know what the error was... i had var routes = require('./routes/index');   in my index.js file. I just removed it and it doesnt give the error anymore. Now going to  check if it actually reads the index.js file for routing

Comment: Yes it works now. Thank god I thought there was a major bug somewhere hidden in my directories. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the  routes = require('./routes/index'); from index.js

Answer (score -1):

Check the file extension and file name of the module file